# Change Project ID in JetBrain's Upsource

Tags: upsource

After creating project in the  JetBrain's Upsource, in edit project "Project ID" is gray, how I can change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProjectID cannot be changed - it is something like "primary key". Only visible project name is alterable

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-10940#focus=Comments-27-5409206.0-0